# How do I deal with mplayer2 forwarding latency?

Tags: video, performance, mplayer, smplayer

I use smplayer as default player on ubuntu 15.04, which is provided by mplayer2 now. It takes mplayer2 more than 3 secs to forward a video, which is unacceptable. On ubuntu 12.04 or 14.04 LTS, smplayer is provided by **mplayer, NOT mplayer2**. It **works nicely**.

Answer (score 1):

Just for forwarding latency go to SMPlayer:

*Preferences/Interface/Seeking/* ***Precise seeking*** and check this option off.

Comment: if this solved your issue please don't forget to mark it as solved.

Comment: Though notice this option affects only mplayer2 and mpv also but it's useless for mplayer.

Answer (score 0):

SMPlayer can be used with `mplayer`, `mplayer2` and `mpv` you can manually set it to whatever you like, sometimes I do set it myself to `mpv` for example. Simply replace the default like on the screenshot:

[image]

To use `mpv` which is recommended by SMPlayer simply type `mpv` instead of `mplayer`.

If you don't have `mpv` installed you can add this ppa with the latest updates for Vivid:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:mc3man/ffmpeg-test1
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install mpv
```

Comment: /usr/bin/mpv -noquiet -nofs -nomouseinput -vc coreserve, -lavdopts threads=4 -sub-fuzziness 1 -identify -slave -vo gl:yuv=2:force-pbo:ati-hack -ao pulse -nokeepaspect -autosync 100 -dr -double -input nodefault-bindings:conf=/dev/null -stop-xscreensaver -wid 75497521 -monitorpixelaspect 1 -ass -embeddedfonts -ass-line-spacing 0 -ass-font-scale 1 -ass-styles /home/yuangg/.config/smplayer/styles.ass -subfont-autoscale 0 -subfont-text-scale 20 -subcp enca:zh:UTF-8 -vid 0 -aid 0 -subpos 100 -volume 16 -cache 100000 -ss 900 -osdlevel 0 -idx -vf-add pp -autoq 6 -vf-add ass -vf-add screenshot

Comment: -noslices -channels 2 -af scaletempo,equalizer=0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0 -softvol -softvol-max 300 /srv/poi.mkv

Error parsing option noquiet (option not found)
Setting command line option '--noquiet=' failed.

Exiting... (Fatal error)

Comment: It crashed. How do I deal with this?

Comment: when did it crash? when switched to mpv? Can you list your basic PC hardware esp. graphics and cpu

Comment: and how do you normally start smplayer? via terminal or GUI?

Comment: It crashed when it played /srv/poi.mkv, using mpv. Hardware: AMD A8 5500 3.0GHz, 8G DDR3 dual channel 1866MHz, Kingston 120G SSD. I usually start smplayer via GUI.

Comment: if you experience issues when playing HD videos like 720p and up then go to smplayer *preferences/performance* and in this tub for *decoding* set the quantity of your cpu cores if it's 4 then put 4 threads if it's 6 then put 6 threads and so on. Also you can use simple *mplayer* engine instead of *mpv* and *mplayer2* as I stated before in my answer.

Comment: if it still doesn't help try to reinstall smplayer from scratch with `sudo apt-get remove --purge smplayer` and then using ppa from my answer `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install smplayer` that's basically the best what you can do by far.